# Render JSON Data into Bootstrap Nested HTML - JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a plugin that accepts data in JSON format. I would like the output to look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ann7tctp/330/

I am trying to setup a recursive function but cannot get my head around it. The nested list depth is unknown. Please see the updated fiddle for more about what I am trying to achieve.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
<html>
<style>
.list-group.list-group-root {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top-width: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group-item {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group > .list-group-item {
    padding-left: 45px;
}

.list-group-item .glyphicon {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

</style>
<h1>Expected Output</h1>
<ul class="list-group list-group-root well">

  <li href="#item-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1
  </li>

  <ul class="list-group collapse" id="item-1">

    <li href="#item-1-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1.1
    </li>

    <ul class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-1">
      <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.1</li>
      <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.2</li>
      <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.3</li>
    </ul>

    <li href="#item-1-2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1.2
    </li>

    <ul class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-2">
      <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.1</li>
      <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.2</li>
      <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.3</li>
    </ul>

    <li href="#item-1-3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1.3
    </li>
    <ul class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-3">
      <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.1</li>
      <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.2</li>
      <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.3</li>
    </ul>

  </ul>

</ul>

<h1>JSON Data Output</h1>

<div id="nested-categories"></div>

<script>
$(function() {

var data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Uncategorized",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Parent 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Child 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Child 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Child 3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Parent 2",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Child 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Child 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Child 3"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var isInitTree = true;

    function buildTreeWithJSONArray(json,root) {

            if(isInitTree){
                isInitTree = false;
                //Create Initial element
                root.append('<ul class="list-group list-group-root in well"></ul>');
            }else{
                root.find("ul:first").append('<ul class="list-group"></ul>');
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                var $li = $("<li class='list-group-item' data-id='" + json[i].id + "'><span class='list-group-content'>" + json[i].name + "</span></li>");

                root.find("ul:first").append($li);

                if (typeof json[i].children !== 'undefined') {

                    //$li.data("toggle","collapse").prepend('<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> ').attr('href','#list-'+json[i].id);

                    //root.find('ul.list-group:first').attr("id",'list-'+json[i].id).addClass('collapse');

                    buildTreeWithJSONArray(json[i].children, $li);
                }
            }
        }


        //Run the Recursive function..

   buildTreeWithJSONArray(data,$("#nested-categories"));




  $('.list-group-item').on('click', function() {
    $('.glyphicon', this)
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right')
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  });

});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening with your code is, when you are calling the recursive function, you are validating whether the root is the init Tree, and of course it will not be as it the variable `isInitTree` has been updated to `false`, hence your code says, it should find a `ul` inside the root element, when in your case, is the `li` element you are sending as a parameter.

It will not find any `ul` elements as there are not any inside the `li` you have sent so it will do nothing.

try:

```
if(isInitTree){
    isInitTree = false;
    //Create Initial element
    root.append('<ul class="list-group list-group-root in well"></ul>');
 }else{
    root.append('<ul class="list-group"></ul>');
}
```

Please see your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ann7tctp/335/), which will hopefully put you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, that is what I tried initially before posting this question. It is still not quite there. Changing that is building the tree <ul> inside the <li> which would work but not with the bootstrap CSS classes.

Comment: see the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ann7tctp/335/), it does what you are looking for, but please be more specific on your questions, Boostrap has a very specific DOM layout needed for it's JS functions to work, you did not mention you intended to achieve that layout explicitly.

Comment: Thanks so much you are a pro! Can you re-update the fiddle and resend me the link please? Is has not saved properly... I will be more specific next time!

Comment: do remember to accept the answer if you've found it helpful, cheers